# Converting matrix to echelon form at python

Tags: python, arrays, sympy, linear-algebra

```
from sympy import *

matrix = []
print("Enter the entries of the 3x3 matrix:")

for i in range(0,3):
    a =[]
    for j in range(0,3):
         a.append(int(input()))
    matrix.append(a)

for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        print(matrix[i][j], end = " ")
    print()
    
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        M[i][j]=list(matrix[i][j])

M_rref = M.rref()
print("The Row echelon form of matrix M and the pivot columns : {}".format(M_rref))
```

I have a error when I transferring arrays to each other. I just wanna convert the 3x3 matrix into echelon form.
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable and sometimes AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rref'

Comment: "I have an error..." What is the error? Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable and sometimes 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rref'

Comment: Please show the full error message. Also double check the code you posted here. Run it. Be sure it causes the exact error you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert your `matrix` to a SymPy `Matrix`, like this:

```
from sympy import *

matrix = []
print("Enter the entries of the 3x3 matrix:")

for i in range(0,3):
    a =[]
    for j in range(0,3):
         a.append(int(input()))
    matrix.append(a)

for i in range(0,3):
    print(matrix[i])

M = Matrix(matrix)
M_rref = M.rref()
print("The Row echelon form of matrix M and the pivot columns : {}".format(M_rref))
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as the solution to your question.